# C# NewtonSoft DeserializeObject error

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, json.net

The strange thing is that it works fine on my local deploy (Win 10 IIS) but when I deploy it to our UAT server, it goes nuts.

I'm trying to deserialize the following json string:

```
{
  "header": {
    "application-code": "ZZZ"
  },
  "piece": [
    "0000001"
  ]
}
```

The classes that represent this are defined:

```
public class RequestPiece
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "header")]
    public RequestHeaderPiece requestheader { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseHeaderPiece
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "application-code")]
    public string application_code { get; set; }
}

public class ResponsePiece
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "header")]
    public ResponseHeaderPiece responseheader { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "piece")]
    public List<string> piece { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I run this code:

```
        public List<string> getP(string pieces)
    {
        try{
            restAPI.Url = config.PieceServiceUrl + "/" + pieces;
            restAPI.Method = "GET";
            restAPI.ClientId = config.ClientId;
            restAPI.Secret = config.SecretKey;
            string returnString = restAPI.callJsonService();
            log.Info(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "::JSON response  => " + returnString);
            ResponsePiece rp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponsePiece>(returnString);
            log.Info(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "::JSON response " + rp.piece);
            return rp.piece;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() + "::failed::" + ex.Message.ToString() + " => " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject is returning the following error:

```
   RequestPid System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] getP(System.String)::failed::System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute.m_memberName =>
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.PerformVisibilityCheckOnField(IntPtr field, Object target, IntPtr declaringType, FieldAttributes attr, UInt32 invocationFlags)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)
   at System.Attribute.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)
   at System.Linq.Set`1.Add(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetAttributes(Object attributeProvider, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAssociateMetadataTypeFromAttribute(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAssociatedMetadataType(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T](Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T](Object provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CachedAttributeGetter`1.GetAttribute(Object type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetCachedAttribute[T](Object attributeProvider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreatePrimitiveContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.GetContractSafe(Type type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at code.RequestP.getP(String pieces) in RequestP.cs:line 51
```

Again, I run the same publish on my local IIS without a problem, so I'm completely stuck.

Comment: Rather than just the traceback of the exception, can you please [edit] your question to share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception, if any?

Comment: Also, you are deserializing the type `ResponsePiece` but in your question you share `RequestPiece`.  Is there any chance you could share `ResponsePiece` instead please?

Comment: What versions of .Net and Json.NET are you using locally and on your IIS server?  Looking at the [source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ReflectionUtils.cs#L767) for `ReflectionUtils.GetAttributes()` it appears `attributes.Union()` is only called for `#if (NET20 || NET35)`.