# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject fails with errorm_memberName

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, .net-3.5

need help with the following. I will appreciate any ideas.

I have some NET 3.5 code to deserialize into a class that works locally with no errors, but not on a Win 2008 server. The exception is:
System.Reflection.DefaultMemberAttribute.m_memberName

The version of the Newtonsoft.json.dll is 12.0.2.23222

The sample json file:

```
{
  "culture":  "sp-MX",
  "dateFormat": "",
  "currencyFormat": "",
  "cultureTranslate": [
    {
      "english": "Company Trend Report",
      "translation": "Reporte de Tendencias",
      "ssrsLocId": ""
    },
    {
      "english": "Start Period:",
      "translation": "Periodo Inicial:",
      "ssrsLocId": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

This is part of a custom assembly that sql server reporting services will load to translate the report labels. 
the report loads OK the assembly loads OK (debugged remotely), but fails when deserializing the file only on the server.

The stack trace is:

```
   at
System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.PerformVisibilityCheckOnField(IntPtr
field, Object target, IntPtr declaringType, FieldAttributes attr,
UInt32 invocationFlags)    at
System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean
doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)    at
System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)    at
System.Attribute.GetHashCode()    at
System.Collections.Generic.ObjectEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
at System.Linq.Set`1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)    at
System.Linq.Set`1.Find(TElement value, Boolean add)    at
System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__81`1.MoveNext()    at
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)    at
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ReflectionUtils.GetAttributes(Object
attributeProvider, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAssociateMetadataTypeFromAttribute(Type
type)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey
key)    at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)  
at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T](Type
type)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector.GetAttribute[T](Object
provider)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract
contract)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreatePrimitiveContract(Type
objectType)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type
objectType)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.AddValue(TKey key)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore`2.Get(TKey key)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type
type)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object
newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract,
JsonProperty member, String id)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
Object existingValue)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader
reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
Object existingValue)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,
Type objectType)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type,
JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,
JsonSerializerSettings settings)    at
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)    at
MStar.Reports.Services.CultureServices.LoadJson(String langFile)
```

```
public class LanguageModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "culture", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string culture { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dateFormat", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string dateFormat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "currencyFormat", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string currencyFormat { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "cultureTranslate", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public IList<CultureTranslate> cultureTranslate { get; set; }
}

public class CultureTranslate
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "english", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string english { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "translation", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string translation { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ssrsLocId", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string ssrsLocId { get; set; }
}

private void LoadJson(string langFile)
{
    try
    {
        var languageJson = File.ReadAllText(langFile);
        languageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LanguageModel>(languageJson);

        //log.Info("Loaded culture file: " + langFile);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Just added below sample code that does not read from a file is:

```
    private void LoadJson(string langFile)        
    {
        try
        {
            //var languageJson = File.ReadAllText(langFile);
            var languageJson = "{ \"culture\":  \"sp-MX\", \"dateFormat\": \"\", \"currencyFormat\": \"\", \"cultureTranslate\": [ { \"english\": \"Company Trend Report\",      \"translation\": \"Reporte de Tendencias\",      \"ssrsLocId\": \"\"    },  {      \"english\": \"Start Period:\",      \"translation\": \"Periodo Inicial:\",      \"ssrsLocId\": \"\"    },  {      \"english\": \"Description\",      \"translation\": \"Descripcion\",      \"ssrsLocId\": \"\"    }  ]}";               
            languageModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LanguageModel>(languageJson);

            //log.Info("Loaded culture file: " + langFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The expected result is to create and populate the LanguageModel object.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] where the JSON was defined **inside the code**. i.e. not reading it from a file. That way we can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: What version of C# are you using? .NET? JSON.NET? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50426850/c-sharp-newtonsoft-deserializeobject-error?rq=1 .

Comment: FYI. I have updated the question. Added sample with json defined in the code and Newtonsoft.json.dll version is 12.0.2.23222. NET 3.5 / C# 3.0. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using .NET 3.5 rather than .NET 4.x?

Comment: Yes. SQL server reporting services 2008 only supports NET 2.0/3.5.